# QGis 2.0.1 mapserver extension missing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mapserver, pyqgis

I tried to export my Qgis projects to mapserver, using RT mapserver extension, because there is not any other extension in my version of QGis.(QGis 2.0.1 Dufour on ubuntu 12.04 LTS). After installing the extension, when i try to export, there is the error:

```
  Une erreur est apparue lors de l'exécution du code python :
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jannes/.qgis2/python/plugins/rt_mapserver_exporter/plugin.py", line 65, in run
    from .mapfileexportdlg import MapfileExportDlg
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "/home/jannes/.qgis2/python/plugins/rt_mapserver_exporter/mapfileexportdlg.py", line 30, in 
    import mapscript
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/utils.py", line 453, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named mapscript

Version de Python :
2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:26:19) 
[GCC 4.6.3]

Version de QGIS :
2.0.1-Dufour Dufour, exported

Chemin vers Python : ['/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing', '/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/jannes/.qgis2/python', '/home/jannes/.qgis2/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/fTools/tools', '/home/jannes/QGis workspace']

How can I solve this problem please?

Answer (score 1):

Your installation misses the python mapscript, or it can not find it.

This is a known bug of the plugin, and has a ticket already:
http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8161

For Windows users, If you have installed QGIS using OSGEO4W setup, you can re-run it by starting osgeo4w-setup.exe again, select `advanced installation` mode, toggle the `View`to full , and select `mapscript-python` from the alphabetical list.

For the standalone installer, I have not yet found a solution :-(

**Update** `python-mapscript` is now part of the `mapserver`package on the Ubuntugis unstable ppa.

Be aware that the plugin is still listed as experimental.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

for ubuntu users :

open software center and search "python-mapscript" and install "python library for MapServer" and enjoy using "RT mapserver exporter".