# Cause of ImportError: No module named mapscript in QGIS mapserver export?

Tags: qgis, mapserver, mapfile

I'm trying to expor project to mapfile in new QGIS Chugiak but a get this error below, someone have the same error? How can I fix this?thnks.

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Artur/.qgis2/python/plugins\rt_mapserver_exporter\plugin.py", line 65, in run
    from .mapfileexportdlg import MapfileExportDlg
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/Artur/.qgis2/python/plugins\rt_mapserver_exporter\mapfileexportdlg.py", line 30, in 
    import mapscript
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 454, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named mapscript


Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.4.0-Chugiak Chugiak, 8fdd08a

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/Artur/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/Artur/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISCH~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\INTERG~1\\ERDASI~1\\usr\\lib\\Win32Release\\python', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISCH~1\\apps\\qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools', 'C:/Users/Artur/Documents/GIS DataBase']
```

Comment: I tried this ans [ans](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84942/qgis-2-0-1-mapserver-extension-missing).

Comment: QGIS LISBOA Works.

Comment: My SO is Win7 Ultimate 64x.

Answer (score 2):

[image: No module named mapscript]

for ubuntu users :

open software center and search "python-mapscript" and install "python library for MapServer" and enjoy using "RT mapserver exporter".

Comment: The question is for a Windows operating system.