# Can QGIS 2.6.1 export to mapserver?

Tags: qgis, mapserver, mapfile

I would know if there's a way to export qgis data to mapserver (Mapfile).
In previous version of Qgis there was a plugin called "Export to Mapserver", now I can't find anything...

Answer (score 3):

The plugin is still alive, now named RT mapserver exporter:

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/rt_mapserver_exporter/

To get it, you need to allow for experimental plugins, and you need the `python-mapscript` package on Linux (part of the ubuntugis mapserver package), or the `mapscript-python` package from OSGEO4W on Windows.

If you run into troubles, see [QGis 2.0.1 mapserver extension missing](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84942/qgis-2-0-1-mapserver-extension-missing)

Comment: Be aware that mapfiles created by this plugin do not work straight ahead for MapServer 6.x and there will probably be more problems with MapServer 7.x. They are still usable as templates. But if you have used the plugin before this is no news for you.

Comment: **Caution:** after you install the plugin, you can find it under **"Web->RT MapServer exporter"**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find a way to install python-mapscript package (and I suppose it is already installed, because with osgeo4w setup rerun it says that no package are missing).
Anyway when I run the plugin RT mapserver exporter, this is the error:

Errore durante l'esecuzione di codice Python:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\rt_mapserver_exporter\plugin.py", line 65, in run
    from .mapfileexportdlg import MapfileExportDlg
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins\rt_mapserver_exporter\mapfileexportdlg.py", line 30, in 
    import mapscript
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named mapscript

Versione Python:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Versione di QGIS:
2.6.1-Brighton Brighton, e2a51df

Percorso Python: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\Programmi\ArcGIS\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.qgis2\python\plugins\MetaSearch\ext-libs', 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGISBR~1\apps\qgis\python\plugins\fTools\tools']

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer. In OSGEO4W, the package is called `mapscript-python`, and you can see it under `advanced install`.